# Infinite Energy with the EmDrive

Tags: physics, energy

Assuming the thrust measured by the EmDrive isn't due to error and it is violating some laws of physics:

Is it possible for one go about exploiting those violations to create infinite free energy?  How?

Assuming the small measured effect cannot be improved upon:

Would friction be a limiting factor given modern material science?

What would a power plant tasked with supplying the entire world's current demand for energy require to build?  Land area, materials etc.

Comment: Hello zwerdlds, welcome to Worldbuilding. Unfortunately, a question like this doesn't really belong on Worldbuilding SE. We're asking and answering questions that come from the building of **fictional** worlds for stories or game settings, but what you are asking regards a controversial **real-world** theory.

Comment: @o.m. I believe that the first line of the question sets it into Sci-Fi territory, no?

Comment: @o.m. Speculating on how a new technology might affect society (speculative fiction) is a significant component to world building.  I also think it's posted here since it almost certainly would be closed on physics.  The chances of the EmDrive actually working (being ground breaking new physics) are very very small.

Comment: @BRPocock, not really, because a sci-fi question would spell out the fictional science of the setting.

Comment: @Jim2B, if the question is *not* about hard data, it should specify a perpetual mobile power plant, not ask for the size.

Comment: @o.m. The bit about size is tertiary to the main question of exploiting the "illegality" of the device.  I can remove that part if its the only thing keeping back this question.

Comment: Also, I'm confused about the "too broad" nature of the hold... it's a yes/no question with an open explanation.  As I understood it, that open explanation portion is what WB is about.

Answer (score 1):

If the EmDrive (or any RF type drive) were to be made feasible, it still has a (high) net energy cost.

The concept is that the radio frequency (EM) energy would be pushed around some type of specially-shaped nacelle to produce a thrust effect, without expelling a propellant like a jet or rocket motor. The energy, though, is still be expended, and radiated off (typically as heat and other EM waves, eg, microwave radiation).

None of the EmDrive-type (Cannae, RF cavity, etc) devices I've seen imagined has been meant to create power, only to perform a (heretofore impossible) conversion directly from EM → kinetic force.

(It seems likely that the “thrust” measurements reported in a couple of tests may be an effect of the attraction of the resonating cavity to its own power supply, actually.)

**Disclaimer:** I am not a physicist at all.

Comment: No worries.  Conversion of energy into thrust doesn't make sense from a units perspective either.  It would be like saying I'm converting the length of a football field into the speed of my car.  It's nonsensical.

Comment: Well, one can convert magnetic attraction into a motive force, so there's certainly a vague sort of precedent for things like that. The unbalanced-ness is the real freak show, here, though, I think: magnets, gravity, et al. pull two things together/apart, never affect only one thing in one direction.

Comment: It's just occurred to me (perhaps I'm particularly stupid) that this is an exact analogue to “pulling oneself up by one's bootstraps”

Comment: If we could figure out a quantum diode that would cause quantum foam energy that is temporarily higher at one point than at another, we'd have either free energy or a lot of burned out diodes.

Comment: Is that effectively the Stargate (TV) “ZPM”?

Comment: It just occurred to me that my analogy is backwards.  It is better stated as "I want a longer car, so I'm going to slow down" (convert some velocity into length).  Photons do have momentum that can be both calculated and measured (this is the principal behind Solar sails).  However, the EmDrive is claiming they get many orders of magnitude more momentum from the photons than any one else can.

Comment: In the later seasons of SG: Atlantis, they put some additional window dressing on the ZPM modules (I think).  They said it opened a window to another Universe.  The ZPM worked as long as the energy in the module was less than the ZPE of that other Universe.  It's all technobabble but this is more likely to work than how they said it worked in SG1.

Comment: @Jim2B: I put energy into an electric motor, I get angular velocity out. The 'missing' units are part of the operating principles of the device that's doing the conversion. The fact that no-one can figure out what the operating principles of the EM drive are other than 'we throw microwaves into a copper tube' is entirely irrelevant if it actually works...

Comment: @BRPocock: One of the theories of how it works (if it works) is that it's pushing off the quantum foam. Zero point energy (and thus ZPMs) is intrinsically bound up with that same concept (though not in the way that SG1's writers wrote it).

Comment: ah. Hadn't heard that explanation. Blame it on the æther :-)